# Missing grails 3.3 plugin jar gson view class files

Tags: grails, gson

Grails 3.3.  I render gson views in a plugin.  During plugin stand-alone run-app the views render fine as expected.  After including the plugin in a main app the views cannot be resolved.  I notice that the published plugin jar has no compiled gson class files in it, only the source gson files.  Shouldn't there be gson class files in the jar?  There is no gradle "compileGsonViews" task in the plugin app.  Also, in Intellij the "build Artifacts" action is disabled.  Shouldn't there also be a jar file artifact?   Am I missing something in my build dependencies?  The only "views" line in build.gradle is

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json:1.2.6"
```

Comment: "Am I missing something in my build dependencies?" - There are many things that might be wrong including something misconfigured in the project or something broken in the framework.  Without seeing your build file it is close to impossible to know if you are missing build dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I was missing some things in build.gradle.  I was missing:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.2.6"
    }
}
apply plugin: "org.grails.plugins.views-json"
```

I should add that this does cause the gson class files to be included in the jar file.  However, it has no effect on the larger issue of the inability to resolve the plugin view classes when running the main application.